# Laravel Use a method from BaseController in a view

Tags: laravel

As I need to get for every page a site configurations variables from a table of my database called 'site_configuration', I use a method in my baseController :

In the `__constructor` i have

```
$this->config = SiteParameter::first();
```

and I have a public method to retrieve a variable :

```
public function getSiteParameter($variable)
{
    return $this->config->$variable;
}
```

If I do `$this->getSiteParameter('sitename')` it works. I'd like to do the same thing in a view. but without passing values to the view. I'd be happy if it was automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the controller __construct to share the config data with the view.  E.g.:

```
public function __construct() {
    View::share('config', $this->config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Config` class, as explained in the [configuration documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#introduction). To put it short, assuming you created a customer configuration file `app/config/site.php`:

```
<h1><?= Config::get('site.sitename') ?></h1>
```

Comment: All datas are from a database

Comment: Then you should edit your question to add that information, as its current wording made me think otherwise, and likely others will too. By the way, you could also use a hook somewhere (maybe a filter to run before the app) to set the `Config` class with the values you took from the database. That way you site will be using the standard way of using configuration, which will be more consistent.

Comment: Yes you're right sry I'll edit my question. The answer of Dave is perfect.